# Calculating times in a range

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to learn Python and I am stuck in a date/time routine I need to find data that occurred between 05:00 and 11:30, but no matter how I go about this I get an error.  I would think that I need decode the time, do the math and then encode the time. I am sure it is a simple thing to do but I cannot seem to get it done.

Example:

```
riders = [
    ["rider_2391", 37_775370, -122.417571, 37_808601, -122.409807, "17:02:35", "$17.23", "UberX"],
    ["rider_1879", 37.775222, 122.47109, 37.808080, -122.410002, "06:25:08",  "$22.25", "UberX"],
    ["rider_98233", 37.784125, -122.471891, 37.763025, 122.478749, "11:48:55", "$6.28",  "Pool"]
]

def getRiderDate(riders):
    ans = []
    for rider in riders:
        if rider[5] >= "05:00:00" and rider[5] <= "11:30:00":
            ans.insert(len(ans), rider)
    return ans

print(getRiderDate(riders)
```

Comment: does the date matter?  (is it included in the data?)

Comment: No. I read several articles. Everything I read dealt with date and not so much time. There was nothing that I read dealt with converting a time format, so that it can be used in a calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is faulty loop control:

```
   for rider in riders:                
            if rider[5] >= "05:00:00" and rider[5] <= "11:30:00":
                    ans.insert(len(ans), rider)
            return ans;
```

You check one rider and return, regardless off the match.  Try this:

```
def getRiderDate(riders):
    ans = []
    for rider in riders:                    
        if rider[5] >= "05:00:00" and rider[5] <= "11:30:00":
            ans.append(rider)

    return ans;
```

`return` goes *after* the loop, not inside.

Output:

```
[['rider_1879', 37.775222, 122.47109, 37.80808, -122.410002, '06:25:08', '$22.25', 'UberX']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use datetime module, mainly time. Also what previous answers are pointing out (return of ans inside of the loop, etc.)

```
import datetime

riders = [["rider_2391", 37_775370, -122.417571, 37_808601, -122_409807, "17:02:35", "$17.23", "UberX"],
          ["rider_1879", 37.775222, 122.47109, 37.808080, -122.410002, "06:25:08", "$22.25", "UberX"],
          ["rider_98233", 37.784125, -122.471891, 37.763025, 122.478749, "11:48:55", "$6.28", "Pool"]]


def getRiderDate(riders):
    ans = []
    t1 = datetime.time(hour=5)
    t2 = datetime.time(hour=11, minute=30)
    for rider in riders:
        t = datetime.datetime.strptime(rider[5], '%H:%M:%S').time()

        if t1 <= t <= t2:  # using chained comparison
            ans.insert(len(ans), rider)
    return ans


print(getRiderDate(riders))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It is a little complicated for my level, but now I have learned something new. It works great!